# SSIS look up on different databases and tables

Tags: ssis

i have the following tables in sql server 2005

- Table TAGSOLD with the columns: TagName, ItemID

And in other database i have the following tables

- Table TAGS with columns: ID, Name
- Table Item_Tags with columsn ItemID, TagID

First i used a SSIS package to fill the table tags from tagsold (it was succeeded since i used a ADO Source and an ADO destination)

Now what i want is to fill the table Item_Tags and i have to select foreach ROW in TAGSOLD look on TAGS to get the tagid and fill the item_tags table.

Could you tell me the right secuence and what kind of items i should use in my SSIS package?

Thanks in advance.

Jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In one data flow get distinct `TagName` from `TAGSOLD` and store in `TAGS`
2. In next data flow get all `TagName`, `ItemID` from `TAGSOLD` and during flow do lookup in `TAGS` by `TagName` from flow = `TAGS.Name` which add `TAGS.ID` to your flow. Store `ItemID` and added `TAGS.ID` in `Item_Tags`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution: use Two sources (TagsOLD and TAGS) with a Merge Join using the common field between both tables TagName=Name and bulding the output based on the table Item_Tags